# Exteding base class with some default column in Sequelize with "Type support" (NestJS)

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have a Sequelize base class with updated_at, created_at columns etc. I want to extend the above base class in order to avoid writing repeated columns in every model. I wanted to have typing support as well (show column names).

Current Implementation.

BaseClass with typing support

```
export type ModelAttrs<T> = Omit<T, keyof Model>


export default class BaseModel<T> extends Model<ModelAttrs<T>, Partial<ModelAttrs<T>>> {
}
```

This will help to show the columns under the base class.

DefaultColumnsBaseClass

```
export default class DefaultValuesModel extends BaseModel<DefaultValuesModel> {

  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    defaultValue: DataType.NOW,
  })
  created_at: Date;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    defaultValue: DataType.NOW,
  })
  updated_at: Date;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
    defaultValue: false,
  })
  is_deleted: Boolean;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    defaultValue: DataType.NOW,
  })
  deleted_at: Date;

}
```

What I want to do is, I want to create `User class by extending DefaultValuesModel` with type support from UserModel and DefaultValuesModel class. So basically the UserModel should show columns from UserModel and DefaultValuesModel.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the BaseModel by referecing the DefaultValuesModel within the Type itself.

```
export type ModelAttrs<T> = Omit<T, keyof Model> & Omit<DefaultValuesModel, keyof Model>

export default class BaseModel<T> extends Model<ModelAttrs<T>, Partial<ModelAttrs<T>>> {
}
```

Now I can extend the BaseClass for type support and default column support.

```
export default class UserIdentityModel extends BaseModel<UserIdentityModel> {
}
```